# Can Swift Generics help a function handle parameters differently based on class?

Tags: optimization, swift, generics

I present the following snippet of Swift code that should be obvious is function:

```
    func loadPage(page: AnyObject) {
        if page is String {
            loadRequest(page as String)
        } else if page is NSURL {
            loadRequest(page as NSURL)
        } else if page is NSURLRequest {
            loadRequest(page as NSURLRequest)
        } else {
            assertionFailure("Unsupported page type")
        }
    }

    private func loadRequest(string: String) {
        loadRequest(NSURL(string: string))
    }

    private func loadRequest(url: NSURL) {
        loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    }

    private func loadRequest(request: NSURLRequest) {
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

I am trying to wrap my head around the power of Generics and am trying to figure out a way that can shorten this snippet using a generic type, but I am not sure that would be an applicable to the pattern here of an single `AnyObject` accepting function that runs that object through an `is/as` comparison. Am I wrong?

Comment: What calls `loadPage`, and how?

Comment: I call loadPage from an external class, but it's just an experiment on being able to pass any object in and handle it accordingly from the single public method without exposing the private functions.

Comment: Generics could be used if creating *multiple* types (read: classes), each handling a specific *type* of "page". Then there is still the process of selecting (and typing the expression for) the correct implementation based on the actual "page" type .. I would probably expose different methods and/or require the caller to do more work upfront in this case. Other patterns (eg. different services/factories/look-ups) become relevant in larger more "enterprisey" code, but also complicate could-be-simple code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a good use-case for generics, since the three types you want to allow in the call to  `loadPage()` can't really be treated in the same way. A generic method is used when a group of types all share a particular attribute or behavior (like `Comparable` or `SequenceType`), but here you're branching specifically so that you can handle each type's differences.

It would be much better to have multiple overloaded `loadPage()` implementations that match your private `loadRequest()` methods -- that way you'll have type-checking and it'll be clear which types are supported as a "page type".